# Border not working properly?

Tags: html, css

Could someone please explain this weird phenomenon:

http://jsfiddle.net/sPA2V/

For some reason, the box footer is thought to be 0px in height (it doesn't take into account the footer's content as height) so the border doesn't show properly. This can be fixed if I float the footer or if set it a fixed height. What if I can't float it and I can't use a fixed height - what are my options then?

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="left"> <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">Products</a> <a href="#">About</a> <a href="#">Contact</a> </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    width:970px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#footer .left {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#footer .left a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 7px;
    color: #969696;
    text-decoration: none;
}​

​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on the #footer.

Comment: This is a trick to make the browser clear floats. You're saying to the browser: don't show scrollbars for this container. But you're not providing any dimensions for that container so the browser tries to adjust the hight of the container to show as much as possible. There are also other ways of clearing floats you can read about here http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear your floats otherwise the parent box (in this case #footer) collapses.

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="left"> 
    <a href="#">Home</a> 
    <a href="#">Products</a> 
    <a href="#">About</a> 
    <a href="#">Contact</a> 
    <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- clear floated elements (anchor tags) on this level -->
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- clear floated element (div.left) on this level -->        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any spaces between the #footer and class name ('left'), i.e. it should be #footer.left and #footer.left a:

Your updated code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sPA2V/1/